# Loginpage in php doesnt work

Tags: php, css

Why doesn't this login page work properly? It doesn't seem to show errors but won't authenticate via mysqli and redirect.

See the code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<!-- saved from url=(0077)file:///C:/Users/Emi/AppData/Local/Temp/Web%20Page%20Maker/Preview/page5.html -->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
            <title>Teacher Login</title>
            <meta name="generator" content="Web Page Maker">
            <style type="text/css">
                /*----------Text Styles----------*/
                .ws6 {font-size: 8px;}
                .ws7 {font-size: 9.3px;}
                .ws8 {font-size: 11px;}
                .ws9 {font-size: 12px;}
                .ws10 {font-size: 13px;}
                .ws11 {font-size: 15px;}
                .ws12 {font-size: 16px;}
                .ws14 {font-size: 19px;}
                .ws16 {font-size: 21px;}
                .ws18 {font-size: 24px;}
                .ws20 {font-size: 27px;}
                .ws22 {font-size: 29px;}
                .ws24 {font-size: 32px;}
                .ws26 {font-size: 35px;}
                .ws28 {font-size: 37px;}
                .ws36 {font-size: 48px;}
                .ws48 {font-size: 64px;}
                .ws72 {font-size: 96px;}
                .wpmd {font-size: 13px;font-family: Arial,Helvetica,Sans-Serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;}
                /*----------Para Styles----------*/
                DIV,UL,OL /* Left */
                {
                 margin-top: 0px;
                 margin-bottom: 0px;
                }
            </style>

            <style type="text/css">
                div#container
                {
                    position:relative;
                    width: 1273px;
                    margin-top: 0px;
                    margin-left: auto;
                    margin-right: auto;
                    text-align:left; 
                }
                body {text-align:center;margin:0}
            </style>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#EBEBEB">
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {
        session_start();
        include 'mysqlconn.php';
        $con = mysqli_connect($host, $dbuser, $pass, $db) or die('Cannot Connect');

        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);

        $sql = "SELECT id FROM tinfoz WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $active = $row['active'];

        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if($count ==1)
        {
            session_register("username");
            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;

            header("Location: newHome.php?login=success");
        }
        else{
            echo '<script type= text/javascript>';
            echo 'alert("Error Please Verify Username and Password")';
            echo '</script>';
            }
    }
    ?>
    <div id="container">
    <div id="roundrect1" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:20px; top:17px; width:1233px; height:591px; z-index:0"><img border="0" width="100%" height="100%" alt="" src="./teacherLogin_files/shapeS1TNG.gif"></div>

    <div id="image1" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:60px; top:48px; width:260px; height:67px; z-index:1"><img src="./teacherLogin_files/text827854609.gif" alt="" title="" border="0" width="260" height="67"></div>

    <div id="hr1" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:64px; top:126px; width:1169px; height:17px; z-index:2">
    <hr size="4" width="1169" color="#C0C0C0">
    </div>

    <div id="hr2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:49px; top:569px; width:1174px; height:17px; z-index:3">
    <hr size="2" width="1174">
    </div>

    <div id="text1" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:49px; top:583px; width:439px; height:24px; z-index:4">
    <div class="wpmd">
    <div><font class="ws8">EM Software Nigeria </font><font class="ws8">©</font><font class="ws8"> 2016 All Rights Reserved</font></div>
    </div></div>

    <div id="text2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:70px; top:151px; width:150px; height:26px; z-index:5">
    <div class="wpmd">
    <div><font face="Verdana" class="ws11">Teacher Login </font></div>
    </div></div>

    <form name="form1" id="form1" action="teacherLogin.php"style="margin:0px">
    <input name="username" type="text" style="position:absolute;width:294px;left:539px;top:247px;z-index:10">
    <input name="password" type="password" style="position:absolute;width:294px;left:538px;top:297px;z-index:11">
    <input name="login" type="submit" value="Login" style="position:absolute;left:644px;top:342px;z-index:12">
    </form>

    <!--[if IE]><div id="table1" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:378px; top:227px; width:513px; height:169px; z-index:7; border:#C0C0C0 1px solid"><![endif]-->
    <!--[if !IE]>--><div id="table1" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:378px; top:227px; width:511px; height:167px; z-index:7; border:#C0C0C0 1px solid"><!--<![endif]-->

    <div class="wpmd">
    <div><table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" bordercolorlight="#C0C0C0" bordercolordark="#808080">
    <tbody><tr valign="top">
    <td width="648" height="305"><br>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    </div>
    </div></div>

    <div id="text3" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:398px; top:251px; width:150px; height:30px; z-index:8">
    <div class="wpmd">
    <div><font face="Verdana" class="ws11">Teacher Staff ID: </font></div>
    </div></div>

    <div id="text4" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:438px; top:298px; width:86px; height:22px; z-index:9">
    <div class="wpmd">
    <div><font face="Verdana" class="ws11">Password: </font></div>
    </div></div>

    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why doesn't it respond?

Comment: Just a tip, use prepared statements, this is very unsafe code..

Comment: The most worrisome thing is not that it doesn't work, but that passwords are stored in plain text in your database.

Comment: It should be `$username = $_SESSION['login_user'];` instead

Comment: *"doesnt seem to show errors"* - Because, you're not checking for them. and you're most likely outputting before header.

Comment: changed to md5, the pass is stored as md5 in db

Comment: You're also using POST arrays but didn't use an explicit post method in the form. Right there, that's an undefined index error.

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code. You now have enough information to debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
  1.          <form name="form1" id="form1"
             action="teacherLogin.php" method="post" style="margin:0px">


 2.   ALSO HERE    

    else{
                    echo '<script type= "text/javascript">';
                    echo 'alert("Error Please Verify Username and Password")';
                    echo '</script>';


                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix the following things :

1) use `post` method in your form.

2) use prepared statement for selecting data.

3) Store your password as `md5` in database.

4) `$active = $row['active'];` this will not work because you have not selected `active` field from database.

5) You have used `$con = mysqli_connect($host, $dbuser, $pass, $db) or die('Cannot Connect');` in same file then why do you require `mysqlconn.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Your form should be:

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" style="margin:0px">
```

The `action="teacherLogin.php"` is not required as your PHP code is processed in the same file, not in another file.

Also, as I have already stated in the comments:

```
$username = $_SESSION['login_user'];
```

It should be this way as `$_SESSION['login_user']` is assigned to variable `$username`, not the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

worked on it now! all works correctlyhad 2 change a few things

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<!-- saved from url=(0077)file:///C:/Users/Emi/AppData/Local/Temp/Web%20Page%20Maker/Preview/page5.html -->
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Teacher Login</title>
<meta name="generator" content="Web Page Maker">
<style type="text/css">
/*----------Text Styles----------*/
.ws6 {font-size: 8px;}
.ws7 {font-size: 9.3px;}
.ws8 {font-size: 11px;}
.ws9 {font-size: 12px;}
.ws10 {font-size: 13px;}
.ws11 {font-size: 15px;}
.ws12 {font-size: 16px;}
.ws14 {font-size: 19px;}
.ws16 {font-size: 21px;}
.ws18 {font-size: 24px;}
.ws20 {font-size: 27px;}
.ws22 {font-size: 29px;}
.ws24 {font-size: 32px;}
.ws26 {font-size: 35px;}
.ws28 {font-size: 37px;}
.ws36 {font-size: 48px;}
.ws48 {font-size: 64px;}
.ws72 {font-size: 96px;}
.wpmd {font-size: 13px;font-family: Arial,Helvetica,Sans-Serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;}
/*----------Para Styles----------*/
DIV,UL,OL /* Left */
{
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
</style>

<style type="text/css">
div#container
{
    position:relative;
    width: 1273px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align:left; 
}
body {text-align:center;margin:0}
</style>

</head>
<body bgcolor="#EBEBEB">
<div id="container">
<div id="roundrect1" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:20px; top:17px; width:1233px; height:591px; z-index:0"><img border="0" width="100%" height="100%" alt="" src="./teacherLogin_files/shapeS1TNG.gif"></div>

<div id="image1" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:60px; top:48px; width:260px; height:67px; z-index:1"><img src="./teacherLogin_files/text827854609.gif" alt="" title="" border="0" width="260" height="67"></div>

<div id="hr1" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:64px; top:126px; width:1169px; height:17px; z-index:2">
<hr size="4" width="1169" color="#C0C0C0">
</div>

<div id="hr2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:49px; top:569px; width:1174px; height:17px; z-index:3">
<hr size="2" width="1174">
</div>

<div id="text1" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:49px; top:583px; width:439px; height:24px; z-index:4">
<div class="wpmd">
<div><font class="ws8">EM Software Nigeria </font><font class="ws8">©</font><font class="ws8"> 2016 All Rights Reserved</font></div>
</div></div>

<div id="text2" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:70px; top:151px; width:150px; height:26px; z-index:5">
<div class="wpmd">
<div><font face="Verdana" class="ws11">Teacher Login </font></div>
</div></div>

<form name="form1" id="form1" action="teacherLogin.php" method="post"style="margin:0px">
<input name="username" type="text" style="position:absolute;width:294px;left:539px;top:247px;z-index:10">
<input name="password" type="password" style="position:absolute;width:294px;left:538px;top:297px;z-index:11">
<input name="login" type="submit" value="Login" style="position:absolute;left:644px;top:342px;z-index:12">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
    session_start();
    include 'mysqlconn.php';
    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $dbuser, $pass, $db) or die('Cannot Connect');

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);

    $sql = "SELECT id FROM tinfoz WHERE username = '$username' AND password = md5('$password')";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    //$active = $row['active'];

    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($count ==1)
    {
        //session_register("username");
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];

        header("Location: newHome.php?login=success");
    }
    else{
        echo '<script type= text/javascript>';
        echo 'alert("Error Please Verify Username and Password")';
        echo '</script>';
        }
}
?>
<!--[if IE]><div id="table1" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:378px; top:227px; width:513px; height:169px; z-index:7; border:#C0C0C0 1px solid"><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>--><div id="table1" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:378px; top:227px; width:511px; height:167px; z-index:7; border:#C0C0C0 1px solid"><!--<![endif]-->

<div class="wpmd">
<div><table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" bordercolorlight="#C0C0C0" bordercolordark="#808080">
<tbody><tr valign="top">
<td width="648" height="305"><br>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
</div></div>

<div id="text3" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:398px; top:251px; width:150px; height:30px; z-index:8">
<div class="wpmd">
<div><font face="Verdana" class="ws11">Teacher Staff ID: </font></div>
</div></div>

<div id="text4" style="position:absolute; overflow:hidden; left:438px; top:298px; width:86px; height:22px; z-index:9">
<div class="wpmd">
<div><font face="Verdana" class="ws11">Password: </font></div>
</div></div>

</div>



</body></html>
```

Everything Seems to work Fine now